# How do I cast a spell in Microlite20?

Tags: magic, microlite20

I'm completely new to Microlite20, and to the D20 system in general.  What, if anything, do I need to roll to cast a spell in Microlite20?  The rules say "Magic Attack Bonus = MIND + level".  Is that required for all spells, or just spells that directly do damage?  And what about spells that don't do damage at all, like Light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Microlite20 and d20, the caster rolls dice if the quantity of success is unknown (damage inflicted, amount conjured), or if a spell must be aimed at a target.  All other spells just succeed.  Even if the caster doesn't roll dice, some spells are resisted by the target, who would need to roll higher than (10 + Caster level + Caster MIND bonus) on a d20 to succeed in resisting.

The magic attack bonus would be used when a spell is used to attack a target, just as a melee attack bonus would be used if a weapon is used to attack a target.  In the case of spells that do not cause damage like a weapon, the caster may still need to touch the target, or aim a ray at the target, and the target may resist by dodging or trying to interpose another object.

With your example, the "Light" spell aimed at an inert object (a tree, a rock, an enemy bound hand and foot) doesn't require a roll determine success.  Someone trying to run away in the dark and would rather not be a beacon leading the chase, that target would resist and require a roll for success.  It's up to the game master to decide what would be appropriate and interesting for the story.

Comment: So if I cast a spell like Sleep that doesn't do damage, does it just happen without a roll? And then each target gets a saving throw?

Comment: Yes no roll. Yes target gets a saving throw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with *Microlite20*, but I know d20 pretty well. Based on my brief glance at the *Microlite20 Gold Edition (V10)* rules, the Magic attack bonus is the modifier you add to a 1d20 for the attack roll for magic spells which require such a thing. The spell descriptors will state whether an attack roll is needed.